# How to convert VARCHAR DATE to Date Format in teradata 15?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I loaded data from csv file with fastload  in Tera Data Express 15. In csv file my ModifiedDate format is 6/12/2004 0:00 and in fastload script my Date type is varchar
I create a new table now I want to load data from one table to another table 
How to convert varchar date to date format?

Comment: You may convert the string into timestamp using the format clause `select cast('06/12/2004 00:00' as timestamp(0) format 'DD/MM/YYYYBHH:MI' )` but you have to fill in a leading `0` for day and hour first. `regexp _replace()` may be of help there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to add missing leading zeroes before casting to a timestamp:

```
Cast(RegExp_Replace(start_date, '\b([0-9])\b', '0\1') AS TIMESTAMP(0) Format 'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi')
```

Of course an easier way would be using TPT (instead of legacy FastLoad) which supports such formats out of the box (VarDate).